# XmlInclude attribute and derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm using Xml serialization to persist some objects on disk.

The class structure is the following:

```
XmlInclude(typeof(BranchExplorerViewInfo))
public class ViewInfo
{
   ...
}

public class BranchExplorerViewInfo : ViewInfo
{
   ...
}

public class CustomBranchExplorerViewInfo: BranchExplorerViewInfo
{
   ...
}
```

Then, I need the following behavior:

```
BranchExplorerViewInfo view = new BranchExplorerViewInfo();
view.GetType().IsSerializable; //I need this to be TRUE

CustomBranchExplorerViewInfo customView = new CustomBranchExplorerViewInfo();
customView.GetType().IsSerializable; //I need this to be FALSE
```

So, I want `BranchExplorerViewInfo` to be serializable but `CustomBranchExplorerViewInfo` to be non-serializable. Is there any attribute to exclude a type/class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean in case you are serializing a property that contains a list of objects of mixed types?

Comment: @Ondrej: I'm serializing the whole class, so I need to exclude the CustomBranchExplorerViewInfo type.

Comment: I think you missed my point: I ask about the place where you use these classes, where the instances to be serialized actually reside. Please provide more code — where you use those classes and what are you actually serializing.

Comment: @Ondrej: The point I'm serializing this is very complex, but there is a central point where I can check if the ViewInfo object is serializable. See my edits, maybe now you can answer the question.

Comment: Rob Levine provided a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two totally different types of serialization.

On the one hand you are talking about `[XmlInclude]` which is related to xml serialization.

On the other hand you are testing `Type.IsSerializable` which is related to binary serialization (ie related to the `[Serializable]` attribute, and the `BinaryFormatter` class).

Although these are both types of serialization, they are very different and unrelated.

There isn't any simple equivalent test of "IsXmlSerialization" that I can think of.